# How to use thrust remove_if 's results

Tags: c++, thrust

I am trying to use thrust remove_if and I have some questions. However first, the example in the [documentation](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction_ga5fa8f86717696de88ab484410b43829b.html) is not working as it should

Here the code (that contains the doc code too)

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

//#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>


#include <iostream>


template<typename T>
struct is_zero {
    __host__ __device__
    auto operator()(T x) const -> bool {
        return x == 0;
    }
};
struct is_even
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const int x)
  {
    return (x % 2) == 0;
  }
};

int main(void){


int h_data[6] = {1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3};

const int N = 6;
int A[N] = {1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7};
int *new_end = thrust::remove_if(A, A + N, is_even());


int * d_data;

cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data, 6 * sizeof(int));

cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data,  6 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_ptr(d_data);
thrust::device_vector<int> output;


thrust::remove_if(dev_ptr, dev_ptr+6, is_zero<int>());
//thrust::remove_if(d_data, d_data+6, is_zero<int>());  //--> segmentation fault



cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, 6 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        std::cout << "H[" << i << "] = " << h_data[i]<< std::endl;


for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        std::cout << "new_end[" << i << "] = " << new_end[i]<< std::endl;

}
```

I run this and I got

```
H[0] = 1
H[1] = 2
H[2] = 1
H[3] = 3
H[4] = 1
H[5] = 3
new_end[0] = 8
new_end[1] = 5
new_end[2] = 7
new_end[3] = -491667200
new_end[4] = 541501445
new_end[5] = 2019959568
```

In the documentation it is said

```
// The first three values of A are now {1, 5, 7}
// Values beyond new_end are unspecified
```

The results of the part  programmed seems to be working (if zero)
But the ones in the tutorial are not the results.

Comment: `new_end` points to `A[3]`, so `new_end[3]` reads beyond the end of `A`.

Comment: You are not printing the contents of `A[0]` through `A[5]`. You are printing the contents of `A[3]` through `A[8]`; the first three of these contain unspecified data per documentation, accessing the remaining three exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: so `new_end` points to the place where` A` should finish??? I certainly didn't see that coming!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Questions about thrust remove\_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67964838/questions-about-thrust-remove-if)

Comment: I recommend you avoid using indexing and start using iterators. Then print up to the returned iterator and no further.