# Questions about thrust remove_if

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have to important questions about how to use thrust's remove_if

1. How can we know how many elements were removed or the size of the new array (once elements are removed)? For example if I have a 6-element array

   int thearray[6] = {1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3};

and I remove the 0's

```
int *new_end = thrust::remove_if(A, A + N, is_zero());
```

I should get `{1,2,1,3}`  but how do I know the result has 4 elements?

2. I tried to use

   `thrust::remove_if(d_data, d_data+6, is_zero<int>());`

where `d_data` was a `int * d_data;` but with memory allocated in the device memory (with `cudaMalloc`  but it gave a segmentation fault. This usually happens when trying to access device memory from the host. So that makes me think. I am trying to keep every operation in the device memory (just downloading to host in the end). Does thrust::remove_if first downloads the data to the Host?

EDIT:
In this

```
int * d_data;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data, 6 * sizeof(int));
cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data,  6 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_ptr(d_data);

thrust::remove_if(dev_ptr, dev_ptr+6, is_zero<int>());
//thrust::remove_if(d_data, d_data+6, is_zero<int>());  //--> segmentation fault
```

you can see that I am wrapping `d_data` with a `device_ptr`. If I do that it works without problem, but if I try to use remove_if on `d_data` itself it crashes

Comment: The variable `new_end` should be a pretty broad hint. The function returns a pointer to the new end of the data. The new end pointer minus the start is the span ("length") of the in place stream compaction result. Also a comment: yesterday you posted a question and in time it took me to copy the code to an editor to compile it, you deleted it. This isn't the first time you have done that. It isn't cool -- you are actively wasting people time when you do this. Please don't. This place is a very finite resource. Please treat it like one.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks, I just noticed the `new_end` thing. My apologies about the delete. It won't happen again. Do you have a guess about the second question? I can provide minimum sample code for that...

Comment: Yes, for that use case with  bare pointers as arguments your need to set an execution policy to let thrust use the correct code path

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. I added the code to compare the option that works and the one that crashes.

Comment: Please take the time to read some thrust documentation. There are two forms of API calls: those using tag based execution selection, and those using explicit execution policies. You need the latter for this use case. If you literally search the thrust documentation for those terms you will find a solution

Comment: Please ask 1 question per question.  That is an expectation for proper usage of SO.  Putting multiple questions in makes duplicate marking (among other things) harder.  The first marked link in the duplicate field is the duplicate for your first question, the second is  the duplicate for the second.